# Web API Controller "Multiple actions found"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using the following get requests to query the below web API controller,

/api/records?aasdfsdf  - Returns everything in Records

/api/records?search=aasdfsdf  - Throws the below error:

> "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGetRecords

Is anyone able to explain what might be the cause?

```
  public IQueryable<Record> GetRecord()
    {
       // return db.Records;
    }


    public IQueryable<Record> GetRecord(String search)
    {
        // return db.Record;
    }

    public IQueryable<Ecg> GetEcgs(String search,DateRange date)
    {
         // return db.Record;
    }

    public class DateRange
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
    }
```

Also what would be the correct way to query:

> public IQueryable GetEcgs(String search,DateRange date)

I've tried the following but I get the same "multiple actions" error. Any help would be much appreciated.

> /api/records?search=asdfsdf?start=2014-09-05%2014:02:17.757&end=2014-09-05%2014:02:17.757

Answer (score 0):

```
/api/records?aasdfsdf
```

This request would route to the GetRecord() method because your query string doesn't have any key value pairs so the only possible route is GetRecord()

```
/api/records?search=aasdfsdf
```

This request could route to both GetRecord(String search) and GetEcgs(String search,DateRange date) with date being null. This is why you have the exception.

You could change the controller to the following to get the routing you need:

```
public IQueryable<Record> GetRecord()
{
   // return db.Records;
}

public object GetRecord(String search, DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
    if( start.HasValue && end.HasValue )
    {
        return this.GetEcgs(search, new DateRange(start,end));
    }

    return this.GetRecord(search);
}

//use private so it's not a possible route or use [NonAction]
private IQueryable<Record> GetRecord(String search)
{
    // return db.Record;
}

private IQueryable<Ecg> GetEcgs(String search, DateRange date)
{
     // return db.Record;
}
```

If Ecg and Record are both of the same base class you could return IQueryable< BaseClass > instead of just object. In our web api projects we don't use a controller to return two different types or we use IHttpActionResult like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetRecord()
{
   // return this.Ok(db.Records);
}

public IHttpActionResult GetRecord(String search, DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
    if( start.HasValue && end.HasValue )
    {
        return this.GetEcgs(search, new DateRange(start,end));
    }

    return this.GetRecord(search);
}

//use private so it's not a possible route or use [NonAction]
private IHttpActionResult GetRecord(String search)
{
    // return this.Ok(db.Record);
}

private IHttpActionResult GetEcgs(String search, DateRange date)
{
     // return this.Ok(db.Record);
}
```

This feels much better than returning "object", but if you have custom filters that will run after the controller, then you'll need to return objects and not results so your usage will vary.